# Saving screen before SDL_RenderClear()?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I’m looking to create a a simple 2D RPG game using SDL2.

I’m kind of stuck in terms of using something like a pause screen I’ll give you a quick example of what I’m wanting to do:
-If the character collects a skill point and they press F1 to open the skill tree, after they have chosen the skill tree they return to the game.

How do I return to the game? I’m guessing that to get to another screen I would need to render clear. Would I need to do anything before I render clear to save everything that has rendered and then re-render it kind of thing? Or would I have to constantly update the position of the player in a variable and everything and then just render everything back in?

Comment: Remember all sdl-2 does is blit graphics to the display. It doesn't remember what it last wrote to the screen. When you want to overlay something on the display (or pause the game), you will have to save the current region or screen, and then blit that back to the display once your operation is done. [Lazy Foo -  Beginning Game Programming v2.0](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/) (excellent reference) provides several examples in the tutorial on how to handle this.

Comment: *"I’m guessing that to get to another screen I would need to render clear. Would I need to do anything before I render clear to save everything that has rendered"* Normally games redraw the entire screen 30+ times per second. So to open the menu you just stop drawing the world and draw the menu instead, and vice versa.